# Help me solve a set problem for my exam preparation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A=\{1 ,2 ,3 ,…, 10\}$

I need to write the following set "C" and I can't seem to understand how

$$C = \{x| x∈A, ∀(y∈A) x+y<14\}$$

Answer (score 1):

In $C$ are all elements $x$ from $A$ such that for all $y$ in $A$ the following is valid $$x+y<14$$

So is it $1$ in $C$? Well, since $1+y<14$ for all $y\in A$ we can conclude that $1\in C$.

What about $2$ or $7$? And all others?